# How to view a function body in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I only get [Function] when I try to display the function :

```
> var a = function(){ return 'toto'; }
undefined
> a
[Function]
> require('util').inspect(a)
'[Function]'
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `toString`:

```
> var a = function(){ return 'toto'; }
undefined
> a.toString()
'function (){ return \'toto\'; }'
```